# Pixel data of an image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimage, pixel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

I want to get a `UIImage`'s pixel values as an array. I am really searching for a predefined function like `getallPixel(theImage)`. How can I figure this out? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the SO post

[How to get pixel data from a UIImage (Cocoa Touch) or CGImage (Core Graphics)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448125/how-to-get-pixel-data-from-a-uiimage-cocoa-touch-or-cgimage-core-graphics)

Here is the blog post for image manipulation retrieving and updating pixel values for a `UIImage`

http://brandontreb.com/image-manipulation-retrieving-and-updating-pixel-values-for-a-uiimage/

Comment: Thanks..Did you ever play with floodfilling algorithms in objective c